# How to install virtualenvwrapper-win on windows 10 without internet access?

Tags: python, windows, pip, offline, virtualenvwrapper

I need to install virtualenvwrapper-win on windows 10 . But that machine doesn't have access to internet. Is there anyway I can download and install it instead of `pip install virtualenvwrapper` ?

I already tried downloading virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4.tar.gz and

```
pip install /PATH/TO/FILE/virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4.tar.gz
```

But I get

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pbr/: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pbr' (maybe misspelled?)
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfofailed -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for pbr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\n2007107\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-_4e665tg-build\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    pbr=True,
  File "c:\users\n2007107\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "c:\users\n2007107\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 315, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
  File "c:\users\n2007107\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "c:\users\n2007107\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 850, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "c:\users\n2007107\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1122, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "c:\users\n2007107\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1134, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "c:\users\n2007107\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 429, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "c:\users\n2007107\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 659, in easy_install
    raise DistutilsError(msg)
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pbr')
```

Answer (score 0):

On an Internet-connected host run

```
pip download virtualenvwrapper-win
```

`pip` downloads the package and all its dependencies. Move all downloaded files to the offline (non-connected) host and run

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=\path\to\downloads virtualenvwrapper-win
```

Replace `\path\to\downloads` with the path to the directory where you moved downloaded installation files.

But I don't see `pbr` as a dependency. If you still cannot install or run virtualenvwrapper-win scripts download and install `pbr` separately.